# Connect MetaMask mobile app to React Native Dapp with DeepLinks

Tags: metamask, dapps, dapp-development, react, dapptools

I'm trying to develop a React Native App that is able to connect directly to metamask(similar to OpenSea).
I've figured out that i need to use a deeplink to open MetaMask, and it works, but what parameters would i need to pass in said DeepLink to make it connect to my DApp? I saw some people saying it was my App URL, but i'm still in testing and didn't really understand how that would work. Does the redirect to the MetaMask app return the address? I just wanted a similiar implementation to OpenSea.
Has anyone been able to accomplish this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You could use the WalletConnect protocol. It is supported by several wallets, metamask, trust wallet, etc.

Comment: I know that's an option, but WalletConnect uses too many wallets, don't want to expose my App to so many vulnerabilities

Comment: @LN0512 did you managed to find any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/react-native-dapp

Use this npm module to connect dapp services.

Comment: I ended up using wallet connect to manage the external wallet connections!

Answer (score 0):

use @metamask/sdk !

https://metamask.io/sdk/

this will help you